# In Emacs, how do I use Tramp SSH to edit as a different group ID?

Tags: emacs, ssh, su, tramp

I think what I'm looking for may be a solution similar to multi hop with SSH and `su`; but instead of `su`, I have to use `sg`. The use case is that I have a user on a server, and the user belongs to multiple groups (main group ID `group_A`, second group ID `group_B`) for administrative reasons. SELinux Access Control is used so even if a directory is owned by me, but if my main group ID is not right, I will not be able to create files. In an interactive session, I would do `chgrp group_B` to switch my main group, and a new shell session will be created. If remotely launching a program, I would do `ssh foo.com 'sg group_B /path/to/executable'`. How do I achieve these effect in Emacs/Tramp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that `ssh`, `su`, etc. are defined in `tramp-methods`, which one can customize as follows to add another connection method called `sg`:

```
(eval-after-load 'tramp
  '(add-to-list
    'tramp-methods
    '("sg"
      (tramp-login-program "sg")
      (tramp-login-args (("-") ("%u")))
      (tramp-remote-shell "/bin/sh")
      (tramp-remote-shell-args ("-c")))))
```

Then one can do

```
C-x C-f /ssh:myuser@remotehost|sg:group_B@remotehost:/path/to/file
```

to connect through multi-hops to `remotehost` as `myuser` using `ssh` and then switch main group from `group_A` to `group_B` using `sg`.

Comment: Nice. May I suggest that you also `M-x report-emacs-bug` to propose this as a new standard method?

Comment: Will do. I've also modified the answer to use `eval-after-load` since Tramp is autoloaded and so tramp-methods is undefined before the first usage.

Comment: Please write the report. I'll add this feature happily to the next Tramp version.